# Find elements in webpage using Selenium in Jmeter

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I want to do testing using selenium webdriver in Jmeter. And i was using `By.linkText` to find an element, and assert whether the element exists or not.

```
var elements = WDS.browser.findElements(pkg.By.linkText("Tools"));
eval(elements.length != 0);
```

But it seems if replace 'Tools' with any other string like 'asfasdsa' it will return True, and my test is passing. It seems `By.linkText` doesnt work in JMeter. Is there any other alternate way to find an element in webpage other than `By.id`??

Also, is this a good way to verify whether an element is present?

Comment: Is there a way, similar to assert, to verify whether an element is present? I want my test to stop when i dont found the element.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can  use [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath):

- Using `text()`:

  ```
  var elements = WDS.browser.findElements(pkg.By.xpath("//*[text()='Tools']"));
  eval(elements.length != 0);
  ```
- Using `contains()`:

  ```
  var elements = WDS.browser.findElements(pkg.By.xpath("//*[contains(., 'Tools')]"));
  eval(elements.length != 0);
  ```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But this eval statement is not similar to assert. I want the test to fail if it the element is not present. How could i accomplish similar in Jmeter?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium works just fine, I'm not sure what you're trying to do with [`eval(elements.length != 0);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) function call, it will return `false` but fail to see where and how you're using this value

If you want to fail the WebDriver Sampler when the number of returned elements is 0 you need to do this a little bit differently, in particular conditionally call [WDS.sampleResult.setSuccessful()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setSuccessful-boolean-) function

Suggested code change:

```
WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get('http://example.com')
var elements = WDS.browser.findElements(org.openqa.selenium.By.linkText('More information...'))
if (elements.length == 0) {
    WDS.sampleResult.setSuccessful(false)
    WDS.sampleResult.setResponseMessage('Failed to find any element matching the criteria')
}
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
```

The above code will pass as long as you don't change `More information...` to something else.

See [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered) for more WebDriver Sampler tops and tricks

Comment: You cannot use "click()" function on the array of elements, you need to choose one of them, i.e. `elements.get(0).click()` - will click 1st element, `elements.get(1).click()` will click second, etc. See [Selenium WebDriver for Beginners](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/selenium-webdriver-for-beginners) for quick ramping up on Selenium, for comprehensive information visit https://www.selenium.dev/ official website